# APScheduler behind Load Balancer

Tags: apscheduler

In reference to APScheduler.

I have a flask app hosted on AWS behind an application elastic load balancer.

Persistent Jobstore is a MySql DB.

So lets say the ELB spins up several (say n=3) EC2 instances of the flask app, and each spawns its own copy of the APScheduler, accessing the same job store, which in principle is fine, however ...

How can I guarantee atomic access of each job in the job store, by only one EC2 instance, however, the overall job store should be distributed across the n=3 EC2 instances. Ie, lets say there were 100 jobs in the queue, approximately 33/34 are to be handled by each EC2 instance, and none are handled by more than one EC2 instance at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I will ask you to read the friendly [FAQ](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes) on this very subject. Long story short: make the scheduler into a microservice.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this seems a little convoluted. If a single jobstore / database is used, why doesn't it act as a pseudo coordinator? For instance with transactions, select/delete/commit, whilst the job is visible and available to all workers, only one worker has the ability to take from the queue.

Comment: The other thing is, with the microservice approach, correct me if I am wrong, but the APscheduler then on the whole becomes the coordinator, and the workers are required to poll at regular intervals asking if anything needs to be done. If there is, then the worker basically takes from the queue and then executes.

Comment: Because as it stands, there is no way for the schedulers to send notifications about the presence of a new job. Likewise, APScheduler lacks a synchronization mechanism to ensure that only one scheduler picks up a job that is due. I intend to fix this shortcoming in v4.0 but that will take time.